# What is the most Pythonic way to raise an exception related to an unexpected file type?

Tags: python

Quick question. I am trying to write reusable code, and haven't found too many other instances of it coming up. Say a script is looking for an XML file, I could just raise a generic RuntimeException, but I am not sure if it would be informative for others using my code, or even the type of thing they would be likely to catch in an except statement. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you use [*FileNotFoundError*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError) ?

Answer (score 4):

You can make your own exception by extending the base `Exception` class.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions